# javascript document.createElement function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable which contains 3 tag names which are separated from each other by a "," character. I want to split them appart with .split() function and then create and append 3 elements to the document body.

```
<head>
<style>
div { height:500px; width:500px; background:#F00; float:left}   
span{display:block; float:right}   
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var element= div,p,span;    
var j=element.split(',')

for(i=0;i<j.length;i++){            
    var crt=document.createElement(j[i])
}

document.body.append(crt)

</script>    
</head>    
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: please indent your code appropriately

Comment: element needs to be a string for a start.

Comment: is the final result supposed to be `<div></div><p></p><span></span>` or `<div><p><span></span></p></div>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'element' variable needs to be a string. You need to use appendChild() rather than append(), and the appendChild() call should be inside your loop:

```
var element = "div,p,span";
var j = element.split(',');
var crt;

for(var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    crt = document.createElement(j[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(crt);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/wEBqY/1

Answer (score 1):

This code seems well, except 2 points:

1. `var element = div,p,span` is not a valid statement, you shoudl wrap quote (**"**) to create a string: `var element = 'div,p,span';`
2. You should put the statement `document.body.append(crt)` in your `for` loop so that each element would be append to `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(i=0; i<j.length; i++)
{            
    var crt = document.createElement(j[i]);
    document.body.append(crt);
}
```

Comment: It's not working because you have other problems in your code such as `var element= div,p,span;` should be a string enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

What the others said PLUS you need to do this onload [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wD5Mb/):

```
<head>
<style>
div { height:500px; width:500px; background:#F00; float:left}   
span{display:block; float:right}   
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var elements= ["div","p","span"];    

window.onload=function() {
  for(var crt,i=0, n=elements.length;i<n;i++){            
    crt=document.createElement(elements[i])
    document.body.appendChild(crt)
  }
}
</script>    
</head>    
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tags = "div,p,span".split(",");

for (var i=0, tag; tag = tags[i++];)
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement(tag));
```

However, the `body` tag is not parsed yet by the browser when you're executing this code, so you should put this code after the `<body>` or run it when the DOM is loaded (`onload` event or `DOMContentLoaded` if supported).

You could also use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) where is supported (ES5, there are plenty of shims, also in the MDN page I linked):

```
var tags = "div,p,span".split(",");

tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement(tag));
});
```

Or if you're using any support library (jquery, underscore, etc) they provide equivalent function.